# Wanting to develop mobile apps which utilise information in an access database?

Tags: android, mysql, ios, ms-access

We currently run a bar loyalty card system. The software is fairly old, and runs off a .mdb database on a single pc. We have moved this to dropbox and use a mdb viewer to allow some minor changes to be made remotely.

To assist our customers we would like to develop a mobile app which tells the customer their points balance allow them to update their address details etc.

I just wondered if it was possible to do this via access? The issue we have is that the software, which is the vital link from the tills to the database requires a .mdb file so creating a newer, more online friendly is not possible.

At the same time we need something which constantly updates, so time based updates to a mySQL database for example I don't think are possible.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

My advice?  Use something like SQLite instead of MS Access.  You may have it, but that doesn't mean your license allows you to install it on client machines.

Why would you want to use it in a multi-client application?  This seems like it can never scale.

Comment: re: "MS Access was designed as a single user desktop database." - Really? Then why does it include (and has always included) page/record locking?

Comment: If MS Access was such a great enterprise database, there would have been no need for MS to lift Sybase and turn it into SQL Server.

Comment: The Access Database Engine ("Jet", now "ACE") was never intended to be an "enterprise database" and there are plenty of sound arguments against using it as a back-end for a web application (for example, the MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database)). I was merely pointing out that your answer included a statement (opinion?) which is simply not true.

Comment: Amended to remove the offending statement.

Comment: Recommending SQLite over Jet/ACE on the basis of concurrent access concerns seems rather bizarre to me given SQLite is as much a file-based database engine as JET/ACE. (Which is not to say SQLite isn't good - since it is! - but that seems a strange way to promote it.)

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me, but I think you may be overstating the need for something that "constantly updates". If by "bar" you mean "establishment that serves alcoholic beverages" then do you *really* need to handle the case where people go on a pub crawl, tossing back pints and checking your mobile app every 5 minutes to watch their points go up?

If that is a *real* business requirement (i.e., one that will incur a significant cost to your business if it is omitted) then you probably need to upgrade your old .mdb-based software anyway. Otherwise, you can have something more scalable than an Access .mdb database as the server-side storage for your mobile app (Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, or similar), which can

- periodically receive updated point totals from the old system, and
- collect address changes (or whatever) from the mobile app, cache them, and push them back to the older system (again, perhaps on a schedule).